# TypeError: findTag.delete is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```js
const tagSchema = require('../schemas/tagSchema')

module.exports = async () => {
    const autoDeleteTag = function () {
        const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime()
        const findTag = tagSchema.findOne({ timeExpired: { $lt: currentTime } })
        if (findTag) {
            findTag.delete()
        }
    }
    setInterval(autoDeleteTag, 120000)
}
```

> TypeError: findTag.delete is not a function

so this piece of code giving me the error I don't know how. The library I'm using here is mongoose.

Comment: please add source code of schemas/tagSchema

Comment: Kindly mention if you are using any library.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DrDK0pzN
tagSchema source code

Comment: sorry, I used mongoose library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after few minutes of looking the code. I forgot to add `await` and `async`